# Opencart: change Featured products limit and dimensions

Tags: css, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using `OpenCart 2.2`

I want to edit the `Featured` module.

Currently there are 4 products displayed, but I want change this to 2.

I know how to change the limit, but I would like that the product blocks would enlarge to fill to 100% width of the frame.

Do I:

1. Change product thumb image size. (Using Settings to change dimensions had no effect)?

   2. Change product block size?

[The goal (click to see an image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pHqQ.png)

Please advise on the best approach to achieve this goal.

Comment: rewritten for grammar, spelling and removal of noise comments

Answer (score 2):

On a fresh install and default theme:

go to `admin panel / extensions / modules` find `featured` and edit `home page`.

set `limit` to `2`, and also set your desired dimensions for `width` and `height`, for example: `400`, `400`

Then open this file:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/featured.tpl
```

find:

```
<div class="product-layout col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

and change it to:

```
<div class="product-layout col-lg-6 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: thanks for help. I also want to learn Opencart CSS basics, because I don't know what is col-lg or col-md. Do you know tutorial?

Comment: Your welcome, If my answer helped you, so please accept it. `col-xx` are not part of Opencart, those belongs to a popular css framework called Bootstrap, Here you can start learning [Bootsrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

Comment: How can I achieve above in the latest OpenCart 3 which now uses twig as its templating language?